# vbscript for executing oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, vbscript, connection

I have a script (not my own) for executing oracle procedure in vbscript. It doesn't work. I set my DSN, user, password etc. ... script run, but procedure didn't run. Please can you correct this script?

> ```
> 'Vbsript to execute a Oracle PL/SQL Procedure
>
> Rem Name of the PROCEDURE
> Dim strProc  : strProc ="POPULATE_EMP_DATA"  
> Rem Name of the DB SCHEMA
> Dim strSchema : strSchema = "bhive_report"
>
>
> '########## TARGET DB DSN
> Dim TargetDSN : TargetDSN  = "devDSN"
> Dim TargetDBuser : TargetDBuser = "devUSER"
> Dim TargetDBpwd : TargetDBpwd = "devPASS"
>
>
> Call runPROC(TargetDSN,TargetDBuser,TargetDBpwd,strProc,strSchema)
>
>
> Rem Sub Routine to Execute Stored Procedure
> Rem Generic accepts DSN name, username, password and procedure name.
> Sub runPROC(vDSN,vUser,vPass,vProc,vSchema)
> On Error Resume Next
> Const adCmdStoredProc = 4
> Dim strTargetConnection : strTargetConnection = "DSN=" & vDSN & ";uid=" & vUSER & ";pwd=" & vPASS&";"
> Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
> objConn.Open strTargetConnection : Rem [ opening Target ORACLE connection ]
> Set CmdStoredProc = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
> With CmdStoredProc 
> Set .ActiveConnection=objConn
>   .CommandText= vSchema & "." & vProc  
>   .CommandType=adCmdStoredProc
>   Set rsProc = .Execute
>   If Err.Number  0 then
>       msgbox "[ERROR]" & Err.Description
>     Else
>       msgbox "Executed Procedure Succesfully - " & .CommandText
>   End If
> End With
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: first line 32 and char 16 "expected then" ... but when I corected line 32 to:   If Err.Number  = 0 then   .... then running OK with message "Executed Procedure Succesfully - " but in database do nothing. Procedure inserting new row in table, but there is no new record.

Comment: any idea? why there isn't error message, but procedure didn't execute?

Comment: What is the PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: It is PL/SQL procedure, which after executing add new row in table with actual date and time. But it works fine, when I executed procedure in SQL Developer. ... When I call procedure through vbscript, procedure does nothing.